# Why is the subtraction of complexity functions the big-O of the minimum of them?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, big-o

Let f(n) and g(n) complexity functions. Why this statement holds true?. How can i prove it?

- f(n) - g(n) is O(min(f(n),g(n)))

Comment: Can f(n) and/or g(n) be negative?

Comment: No since they´re complexity functions

Comment: @Dukeling `f(n)-g(n)` is indeed `O(max(f(n),g(n)))` because it is `O(f(n))`, but that seems an unnecessarily weak statement.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Actually I'm not sure it would be `O(max(f(n),g(n)))`. What if g(n) > f(n)? Then we'd have a negative result. I'm not really sure what would happen in that case. Or do we just define it as 0 for values < 0? In this case it definitely won't be `O(max(f(n),g(n)))`.

Comment: @Dukeling The question would indeed be more complicated if `g(n)` could be negative, so I got confirmation that both functions are non-negative in the first two comments on the question.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Even if both functions are positive, we can still have `g(n) > f(n)` and thus `f(n) - g(n)` be negative.

Answer (score 6):

The proposition is clearly false. Consider `f(n)=n` and `g(n)=0`. `min(f(n),g(n))` is zero for `n>=0`, but `f(n)-g(n) = n`, which is not `O(0)`.

*For every `n>=0`, `f(n)-g(n) <= f(n)` so `f(n)-g(n)` is `O(f(n))`. I think that is the strongest statement that can be made in general, without a lower bound on `g(n)` that is a positive function of `n`.*

==========================================================================

The second paragraph above is incorrect, because, as @Dukeling pointed out in a comment, `g(n)` may be so big that `f(n)-g(n)` is negative, possibly with an absolute magnitude greater than `f(n)`. What happens in that case depends on the definition of big-O.

A [NIST](http://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/HTML/bigOnotation.html) web page defines it as follows: "Formal Definition: f(n) = O(g(n)) means there are positive constants c and k, such that 0 ≤ f(n) ≤ cg(n) for all n ≥ k. The values of c and k must be fixed for the function f and must not depend on n."

By that definition, a function that for every positive number `k` has at least one `n>=k` for which `f(n)` is negative is not big-O anything.

A [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) page defines it as follows (converted to ASCII): `f(x) = O(g(x))` if and only if there exists a positive real number `M` and a real number `x_0` such that

```
|f(x)| <=  M |g(x)|  for all x>x_0
```

This definition does allow use of big-O notation for a function that is negative for large argument values, by working with its absolute value. With this definition, `f(n)-g(n)` is `O(max(f(n),g(n)))`.

Answer (score 0):

The statement is actually false. First, note that O deals with magnitudes, so the sign of f and/or g is irrelevant. The correct relationship is

> O(|f(n)| + |g(n)|)

(see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Sum) for instance). If |f| grows faster than |g|, then |f| is going to asymptotically dominate |f-g|, and likewise if the converse is true.

If there are other facts about f and g that are not in your post (e.g., that both functions are always negative), then it may be possible that O(|f| + |g|) = O(min(f, g)) (= O(|min(f, g)|)).

Comment: I didn't read the question as asking about the complexity of computing `f(n)-g(n)`, but about whether the complexity function `h` is in `O(min(f(n),g(n)))` if `h` is equal to `f(n)-g(n)`.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan - on rereading the question, I agree entirely. It's not about complexity of computing f or g, but about the growth of f, g, and (f - g). I reworded my answer.